# Show that every finite group of order $n$ is isomorphic to a group consisting of $n\times n$ permutation matrices.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I solved the problem myself and I'm curious if this is legitimate.
I used that if a group of order $n$, $X$, is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A$,
$X$ should be also isomorphic to a subgroup of $B$ if $A$ and $B$ is isomorphic.

(because I think this is an isomorphic structure?)

Please help me if there is any error.
Thank you!

> A **permutation matrix** is one that can be obtained from an identity matrix by reordering its rows. If $P$ is an $n\times n $ permutation matrix and $A$ is any $n\times n$ matrix and $C=PA$, then $C$ can be obtained from $A$ by making precisely the same reordering of the rows of $A$ as the reordering of the rows which produced $P$ from $I_n$.
>
> $\textbf{a.}\,\,$ Show that every finite group of order $n$ is isomorphic to a group consisting of $n\times n$ $\quad\,\,\,$permutation matrices undert matrix multiplication.
>
> $\textbf{b.}\,\,$ For each of the four elements $e,a,b$, and $c$ in the Table $5.11$ for the group $V$, give a $\quad\,\,\,$specific $4\times 4$ matrix that corresponds to it under such an isomorphism.

Comment: Yeah, on the first part the most important part is probably the one that you say you will prove later (namely that the group of permutation matrices is isomorphic to $S_{|G|}$, for the second one you have to just check the relations ($ab=c$, does the image of $a$ times image of $b$ equal the image of $c$?, and so on). Best.

Comment: The isomorphism is not hard. If $f : X \rightarrow G \le A$ and $g : A \rightarrow B$ are your given isomorphisms, then $g \circ f$ is an isomorphism of $X$ to a subgroup of $B$.

Comment: I think the title is misleading (or completely wrong, if you will): it must be "...consisting of $\,n\times n\,$ permutation **matrices** "

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Wait. I just proved that a group of n by n permutation matrix, Pn, is isomorphic to S_G, since by cayley theorem, a group of n by n permutation matrix should be isomorphic to a subgroup of S_G, but, at the same time, the order of Pn and the order of S_G is equal. Therefore, Pn should be equal to S_G, rather than propler subgroup of S_G. Is this right?

Comment: Cayley's theorem doesn't say that $P_n$ is isomorphic to $S_G$. ($G$ is your group of size $n$. $P_n$ has size far bigger than $n$, though. Cayley's theorem says it's isomorphic to some subgroup of $S_{P_n}$, which isn't what you wanted to show.) You'll need to show that directly (which you promised to do in the attached image, but didn't seem to do - you gave an example of it when n = 4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used that if a group of order $n$, $X$, is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A$, $X$ should be also isomorphic to a subgroup of $B$ if $A$ and $B$ is isomorphic.

Yes. "$X$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A$" is the same as saying "there is an injective homomorphism $f: X\to A$". And "$A$ is isomorphic to $B$" is the same as saying "there is a bijective homomorphism $g: A\to B$". It's easy to see that $g\circ f: X\to B$ is an injective homomorphism, i.e. $X$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $B$. (Actually, $g$ doesn't need to be surjective.) As long as all of your maps are structure-preserving, the structure gets preserved no matter how many maps you hit it with!

You now need to show that $P_n$ is isomorphic to $S_G$, where $G$ is a group of size $n$. Well, $P_n$ is a group of $n\times n$ matrices, so I recommend you pick a basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ for those matrices; and $S_G$ is the permutation group of a set of size $n$, so I recommend you give the elements of that set names, say $g_1, \dots, g_n$. An element of $P_n$ just swaps around the $e_i$; an element of $S_G$ just swaps around the $g_i$. Can you see how the isomorphism $P_n \to S_G$ works?